# How does redux-promise know which result to return in this weird situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm following this course on udemy: https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/learn/v4/t/lecture/6946622?start=0  (paywall, i know, sorry)

The setup is like this, in an action creator, I have this code

```
export function createPost(values, callback){
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, values)
        .then(()=>callback());

    return {
        type: CREATE_POST,
        payload: request,
    }
}
```

I'm using redux-promise middleware to have this promise resolved, so in the reducer I can have something like this

```
export default function postReducer(state = {}, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case FETCH_POSTS:
            return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, "id");


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

(ALso using lodash, you'll notice the underscore)

From the documentation on promises, I understood that the value "returned" by a chanied is the last value returned by the last promise.

However here the callback passed here `.then(()=>callback())` returns `undefined`. How come my code works (so I'm getting back the body of the HTTP call that I made)?

I'd expect that in the reducer, the payload key would have the value of undefined.

Can someone explain this black bagic here?

(I am not a guru in JS, I code mostly python. Also, I'm a total noob to react)

**[EDIT]**
More clarifications:

My callback:
`const callback = ()=>{this.props.history.push('/')}`

The callback works, because it does redirect me back to the index page. I pass the callback from a component. Notice, the callback doesn't return anything.

I expect that when the reducer is called, `action.payload` should be `undefined`
Actual result: `action.payload` is actually an object.

I'd expect the code to work if i hadn't chained another promise. So in the case when `const request = axios.post(...)` I'd have no problem understanding that the value wrapped in the promise is the body of the request. However, since I'm using a chained promise, I'd expect my end result, resolved by `redux-promise` to be the value returned by the callback in the last promise.

Comment: `.then(()=>callback())` doesn't return `undefined`, it returns (a promise for) the result of `callback()`. Which might or might not be `undefined`.

Comment: (Of course `createPost` should absolutely not take a `callback` parameter at all. It should just directly return the promise).

Comment: @Bergi I'm very new to react. The guy in the tutorial said I should do that. That's all the context. Even though I appreciate best practice advice (and I'll check reducers out some more), I'd really like to know why the result that I receive (reducer receives a payload with data) doesn't match what I expect (reducer receives a payload with undefined in it).

Answer (score 0):

You loosing the result, because you not passing it from `then` function.
Here is example how to use it:

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, values)
    .then((resultFromPost)=>{callback(resultFromPost)});
```

or

```
const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, values)
   .then(callback);
```

Comment: I'm not losing the result, that's the point. I am getting back a "good" result (a body of a HTTP response). However I don't understand why. From that code, I'd expect to get back `undefined`. I don't get `undefined` back, but I get a JSON. I'l try to clarify this more.